# VBA, Avoid Overflow Error, Trim worksheet function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an overflow error on my attempt to trim cells within my range. The line I get the error on is, `C.Value = .Trim(C.Value)`  Perhaps this can be done without intersect? I've tried without it but it leads to mismatch error.

```
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim dailyWB As Workbook
    Dim C As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
    'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
    Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open("excelguy.xlsm")


    'Copy the Range from dailyWB and Paste it into the MasterWB
    dailyWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:BJ200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("Master Summary").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
    'formatting and paste as values
    Workbooks("excelguy Master.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Master Summary").Select

    'trim values
    columns("A:BJ").Select
       With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each C In Intersect(columns("A:BJ"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)  
            C.Value = .Trim(C.Value)  'Overflow Error
        Next C
        End With
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need `Application.WorksheetFunction` to use `Trim` in VBA - `Trim` as a standalone function works just fine.

Comment: What is `C.Value` when it errors?

Comment: @dwirony `WorksheetFunction.Trim` and `Trim` work differently. Both will remove leading and trailing spaces from a string but `WorksheetFunction.Trim` will also convert double spacing to singular spacing in the middle of a string.

Comment: @Tom Huh... I never knew that! I didn't think people used `Trim` to remove double spaces in sentences... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is a date actually. `30/11/2015` and a bunch of "Emptys" . But I believe close to the error is the date.

Answer (score 3):

1. No need to `.Select` or `.Activate` your workbooks/sheets. You declared workbook variables so **use them**!
2. `UsedRange` can be unreliable. I recomend switching to a more standard last row calculation. Right now, the code is using `Column A` to determine last row for all columns in your range, which in return determines the range you are going to loop through.
3. As stated by @dwirony, the `TRIM` function can be called directly from `VBA`.

*Please see comment from @Tim Williams below to determine if the VBA version of Trim is acceptable*

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim masterWB As Workbook, dailyWB As Workbook
Dim C As Range, LRow As Long

Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open("excelguy.xlsm")

dailyWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:BJ200").Copy masterWB.Sheets("Master Summary").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")

With masterWB.Sheets("Master Summary")
  LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each C In .Range("A2:BJ" & LRow)
        C.Value = Trim(C)
        'C.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(C)
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

If you are just trimming the values, you could load your range into an array, modify the values into a new array, and then do a value transfer of your new trimmed array to a range

Comment: Note that VBA `Trim()` and the `TRIM()` worksheet function do not perform the same operation...  "The Excel TRIM function strips extra spaces from text, leaving only a single space between words and no space characters at the start or end of the text" - the VBA version only trims leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: @TimWilliams I did not know that. Thank you!

Comment: @urdearboy I want to trim the extra space on the end of a word. The space in the middle should still be there.

Comment: Im still getting an error on `C.Value = Trim(C)` . And yes sounds like I want to use the VBA Version to remove extra uneeded spaces. Not sure what I am doing wrong . I did change last row to Column B because that where the data is.

Comment: Do you have any error values from formulas in your range? Step through your code using `F8` to see what the value is when the code error =s out

Comment: Wait is this the right workbook I am referencing? I want to trim on the masterWB. Thats why I activate it. My fault, in the code I make it look like its the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  To use Variant Array is faster.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim masterWB As Workbook, dailyWB As Workbook
    Dim C As Range, LRow As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set masterWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set dailyWB = Workbooks.Open("excelguy.xlsm")
    Set Ws = masterWB.Sheets("Master Summary")

    dailyWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:BJ200").Copy Ws.Range("A1")
    Ws.Activate
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .UsedRange
        vDB = rngDB
        For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
                vDB(i, j) = Trim(vDB(i, j))
            Next j
        Next i
        rngDB = vDB
    End With

End Sub
```