# Excel VBA WorksheetFunction.TRIM overflow error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into an overflow error when I run the code below on one of my worksheets. It seems to run fine all my others others and while this one is a bit larger (Ending at V1206) I wouldn't expect it to return Error 6, Overflow.

If I empty cell J46, it overflows at J45. If I then empty J45, it breaks all the way back at F48. I'm obviously missing something but since it's only overflowing on simple names or dates I'm not quite sure if it's something in the cell or my code itself as I'm relatively inexperienced with Excel's VBA environment.

```
Sub NoSpaceversion2b() 
Dim Range, Cell As Range
Dim strSheet As String: strSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'This stops at cell I47 (value M)
'Set Range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'This will get it all the way to cell J46 (value 12/3/1967)
Set Range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each Cell In Range
    Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cell)
    Debug.Print "Cell " & Cell.Address & " ; " & Cell.Value; " trimmed"
Next Cell

MsgBox "All Leading/Trailing spaces removed on worksheet '" & strSheet & "'.", vbOKOnly, "Operation Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use the VBA `TRIM` function, not the worksheet one.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53485664/vba-avoid-overflow-error-trim-worksheet-function

Comment: I was hoping to make one function do, as I wanted to get rid of any potential double spaces between words in a string at the same time.

Comment: After trying the above: Changing `Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cell)` to `Cell.Value = Trim(Cell)` produces the overflow in the same spots.

Comment: What is the value of the spots in which it overflows? Or the value before?

Comment: Just wondering - are you sure you are not assigning somehow the value to an Integer in your code, (e.g., using something else but the one posted)? Because if a date is assigned to an integer, then after 16/Sep/1989 it should throw an overflow...

Comment: Possible, but I'm not sure how I'd resolve that if it is happening. One value is a first name, another "M", and another "12/3/1967". Presented code is complete with the exception of `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Would I have to load cell contents into a Variant, run the trim, and then push it back into the cell? It just seems to be this one particular worksheet and it's only exception in comparison to the others for its size, general content is the same. Edit: Changing date to 2/9/1953 still leads to the initial overflow in the same spot.

Comment: Did you have a look at the link I've included in my comment?  It explains your problem in more detail, it's not just the `TRIM` function, it's your usage of `Cell.Value` instead of just 'cell(whatever,whatever) = Trim(cell(whatever, whatever))`.

Comment: I did, yes. Just working in adopting it. If I understand correctly, I need to replace .UsedRange with a more narrowly defined LastRow/Column method.

Comment: I think that, without a sample workbook that reproduces the problem, it is going to very difficult to analyze what's causing the error.  There've been a few other reports that seem to implicate the date data in a cell, but nothing definitive that I've found as to the cause of the overflow error, and why it doesn't happen all the time with a date.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're probably right. If it was only ever the dates it would at least make more sense, but failing on names and single characters only makes it stranger. Changing the code over to     `With ws1  LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  For Each Cell In .Range("A2:Z" & LastRow)  Cell.Value = Trim(Cell)  Next Cell  End With` doesn't seem to resolve it, but this is likely my implementation. Apologies for the code formatting as well.

Comment: I wonder... I47 errors. Next column over is "19621126" as a date that just displays a bunch of #'s in the cell. Removing that brings me to I61. Next column has the same issue, "19760102" as date displayed as a bunch of #'s. New code seems to be working a treat, it's just these things erroring it out. Good catch, @RonRosenfeld !